# EXCEL - SUM column if date matches TODAY()

Tags: excel, formula

I've tried using SUMIF to obtain my results but it doesn't work properly.

I have a row of dates (XX/XX/XXXX format) and I would like to check this row for the current date.

If the row contains the current date, then I would like to sum the total of that column and row 5-20.

For example - today is 10/13/2016. I would like to search for TODAY() in a certain row (Row 1 for example), and if TODAY() is found, then total this column from row 1 down to row 3.

```
      --A--      --B--
   10/13/2016   10/14/16
1     50           10
2     10            4
3     5             6
```

The result should be 65 only IF the date matches TODAY().

I've also checked on giving the column letter based on the date but with no luck.

Any tips are appeciated! Thank you.

Comment: Firstly, what should it be if it's not? Illpratll's solution should work (albeit not to your original definition but to the example given, I still take it as answered though). `TODAY()` is dynamic, it changes to today's date.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with a simple IF and a SUM

i.e. in your example above if you want the result to appear on the bottom row you can just use:

```
=if(B2=today(), sum(B3:B5), "")
```

This will display the sum at the bottom of the column for columns where the date = today and a blank in the other columns

[image: screenshot]

Comment: that will work for an absolute value - I need it to by dynamic. I need the values for todays date, since today will change daily

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here, as AER said I'm using today() which is dynamic, there is actually a result in every column in the bottom row, they are just "" when the date <> to today. If you are saying you want todays result in a single cell instead of just a the bottom of a specific column you could sum that entire row into a cell, seeing as only todays result will be displayed in that row

Comment: This formula will determine if F2 = TODAY() and then sum F3:F5, that is fine if F2 is always today, it will work. What about tomorrow when F3 is now today?? This formula will no longer work.

Comment: you mean tomorrow when G2 is today

it will still work, like I said the formula is there in E6 the same as its in F6 its just not visible, presumably tomorrow when you have a new column of data you can extend the formula in F6 one cell to the right, you could extend it today if you want, will still work ;)

Comment: This would work if the original sheet can be modified, I'm sorry that I didn't specify that. The original sheet has to remain as is.

Comment: I guess there is no way around it, I'll need an IF statement for every cell on the original sheet, which is like 30 to check the date and if the date is in there, then add the cells needed. i was hoping i could shorten it, but i guess not.

Comment: you could actually solve this using my formula without modifying the original sheet, create a new sheet and in cell A1 you can use the same formula:

=IF('Sheet1'!F2=TODAY(), SUM('Sheet1'!F3:F5), "")

then extend this to the right for future dates, your new sheet will have a single result in row A that corresponds to the column in your original sheet with todays date, you can then sum all of row A to get your result

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the OFFSET function.  You can find the documentation here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-C8DE19AE-DD79-4B9B-A14E-B4D906D11B66

In your particular example the following formula will work:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(D2, 1, MATCH(B2, $D$2:$F$2, FALSE) - 1, 20))
```

You can see the formula working below.  Assuming you know what the SUM formula is doing, I will explain what the OFFSET formula is doing:

- First Parameter: Says start at cell D2
- Second Parameter: This is how many row up/down do you want to do.  In your case you need start at row below the date so '1' it is.
- Third Parameter: This is how many columns to the right do you want to
  go.  Well the number of columns you want to go is based upon where
  your date is.  So this uses the match formula to figure out how far
  to the right to go.
- Fourth Parameter: This is how many row do you want to include.  I just picked 20 to include the 20 rows below the selected cell.

You obviously need to modify the parameters a little bit to fit your exact data shape.

[image]
[image]

Comment: HLOOKUP would do the same thing no?

Comment: HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP return a row (as far as I know).  @lllpratll needs to return a range so he can sum the whole range.

Comment: Correct, it returns a range if you define rows/columns as a set {1,2,3} and then use it as an array formula. Refer to my answer.

Comment: @AER yep, good point.  Either would work.  I guess just a question of style at that point.

Answer (score 0):

So I'll give it a shot:

```
{=SUM(HLOOKUP(TODAY(),Table_With_Dates_and_Three_Rows_Cell_Reference,{2,3,4}))}
```

NB: Don't type `{}` but put the formula inside it and then hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter to create what is called an array formula (it does array calculations element by element then submits the aggregating function value---in this case that is sum).